# Opening jar in fullscreen in terminal

Tags: raspbian, java

How can I open a JAR file in fullscreen?

I mean that kind of fullscreen that it hides taskbar and other stuff like videogames in fullscreen mode.

I remember finding a way a couple of months ago but I don't remember it anymore.

So I run the file using:

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

Comment: What program are you running? This will likely depend on the exact Java app you use.

Comment: Some java program that my friend made

Comment: I believe this feature has to be implemented by the developer. Like in Minecraft, for example

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to force a JAR file (or any other executable for that matter) in fullscreen mode, if the executable doesn't support it.

You can try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while the JAR runs, or run it with `--fullscreen` option. If that doesn't work, ask the developer to implement fullscreen mode.